# Связь между моделями ManyToMany через промежуточную модель

Tags: python, django, django-model

Нужно построить связь между моделями `ManyToMany` через промежуточную модель для рассылки писем

Делаю рассылку писем для подписчиков. Письма отправляются при добавлении нового поста. Не могу добраться от Post до Category (связь идет через PostCategory).

model.py:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    postCategory = models.ManyToManyField(Category, through='PostCategory')
    ...

class PostCategory(models.Model):
    postThrough = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    categoryThrough = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=True)
    subscribers = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, related_name='subscription', verbose_name='Подписчики')
```

Сама рассылка:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Post)
def notify_users_post(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    pass
```

В instance получаем созданный объект, в данном случае объект Post. Чтобы сделать рассылку, нужно получить id или названия категорий для данного поста. Далее перебираем подписчиков данных категорий и рассылаем им уведомления на почту.

Вопрос: как добраться до категории через instance?

Comment: `instance.postCategory.all()` ?

Answer (score 1):

В вашем случае стоит задача использовать PostCategory в качестве промежуточной модели? Насколько я помню, в джанго можно реализовать это проще, она сама создаст промежуточную таблицу при миграции. Приложу ссылку из документации, где подробно расписан процесс связи MtM. Достаточно будет двух моделей Post и Category
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

Answer (score 1):

```
categories = Category.objects.filter(postcategory__postThrough=instance)   # находим категории данного поста
subscribers_mail = []
for category in categories:   # перебираем категории
    for sub in category.subscribers.values('email'):    # перебираем email подписчиков
        subscribers_mail.append(sub['email'])   # на выходе получаем список адресов для рассылки
```